# External hard disk is not detected by using fdisk -l and in /dev/disk/by-path/

Tags: hard-drive

I am using SATA internal hard disk as an external hard disk by using hard drive enclosure on ubuntu 20.04 but when I use command  `fdisk -l`, it is not detected and also I can't see it in  `/dev/disk/by-path` but when I use other external hard disk, then I can see it. I think there is a problem with the disk, maybe it is defective. My question is, can I do something to fix it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you use the same enclosure with the other external HDD? Can you temporarily connect the drive internally? If it works your issue is with the enclosure, its connection or a software problem

Comment: @PonJar, Previously I replaced my internal HDD with ssd because it was showing 3f0 hard disk error and it was not being checked quick or extensive by the system and when I used this internal HDD as an external hard disk using an enclosure, it is not being detected. Other external HDD does not need enclosure. It gets connected directly. I guess there is a problem with disk but I don't know how to check whether it is defective or not and data is still on the disk or not. If possible, please help.

Comment: Does enclosure use separate power or just USB? USB often does not have enough power for HDD. I have an USB only adapter that works great with my SSD, but with HDD not seen & does not even spin up.

Comment: @oldfred, enclosure uses USB only.

Comment: Sounds like the enclosure may not be suitable for the HDD. Do you have a powered usb hub?. You might have more luck with that or perhaps a different USB port on your machine.

Comment: @PonJar Thank you for the response. I don't have powered usb hub. I'll buy or will check it with different enclosure or with caddy again.